# Kernel Interpolation with Barrier

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst

I am trying to use the 'kernel interpolation with barriers' tool in the Geostatistical Analyst toolbox of ArcGIS 10.3. My data consists of 600 marine animal relocations, and I am trying to calculate the kernel density estimate using a polygon shapefile of the coastline as a barrier (the animals do not use land).

My relocations all have the same weight (i.e., the z- value for all points is 1).

I initially tried the tool by setting the function to 'gaussian' and the 'order of polynomial' to 0. this was based on the parameters used in the paper *"Three-dimensional foraging habitat use and niche partitioning in two sympatric seabird species, Phalacrocorax auritus and P. penicillatus" by Adam G. Peck-Richardson et al (2017).*

After running for 4.5 hrs, the output was completely useless, where all the cells had a value of 1.

I don't see a lot of documentation for this tool, and I don't understand why I got an output with a uniform value. Any insight?

Comment: I found quite a lot of documentation to be available for this tool, as well as recommendations for further reading in the second of these links: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/geostatistical-analyst-toolbox/kernel-interpolation-with-barriers.htm and http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/how-kernel-interpolation-with-barriers-works.htm

Comment: A screen shot of how you set up the tool would be useful too. Amend your question with that.

Answer (score 1):

This analysis is far too complex to explain in detail here, but I found a textbook that provides step-by-step examples.

"An introduction to using GIS in marine biology supplementary workbook four: investigating home ranges of individual animals" by Colin D. MacLeod.

Answer (score 0):

I am on ArcGIS Pro team. We just released an update I have been working on to Kernel Density tool that includes optional barriers parameter. I think this is exactly what you are looking for. You can see more information on this here  https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/spatial-analyst/analytics/whats-new-for-spatial-analyst-in-arcgis-pro-2-6/

This is only included in ArcGIS Pro, so if you are still using ArcMap, I suggest switching to Pro.